Delphi XE 10 Windows Service: TBackgroundThread.Execute Not Running After Service Start
Question:
I'm developing a Windows Service using Delphi XE 10. The service installs and starts without any issues, but it seems that the TBackgroundThread.Execute method is not running as expected. I know this because I'm not seeing any logs that should be generated within the Execute method.
Here’s a brief overview of my setup:
Service Initialization: In the ServiceStart event, I create and start a background thread (TBackgroundThread).
Logging: I'm using CnDebugger.LogMsg to log messages in the Execute method of the thread, which should run every second.
Thread Execution: The Execute method has a loop that logs the current timestamp every second.

Code Snippets:
ServiceStart Method:
procedure TService1.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  FBackgroundThread := TBackgroundThread.Create(True);
  FBackgroundThread.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FBackgroundThread.Start;
  Started := True;
end;

TBackgroundThread.Execute Method:
procedure TBackgroundThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    if not FPaused then
    begin
      CnDebugger.LogMsg(DateTimeToStr(Now));
    end;
    TThread.Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

Despite the service starting correctly, the logs inside the Execute method of TBackgroundThread are not being generated, indicating that the Execute method is not running.
Ensured that FBackgroundThread is initialized and started.
Checked service permissions to ensure it can execute threads and write logs.
Verified that logging via CnDebugger.LogMsg works in other parts of the service.
What might be preventing the TBackgroundThread.Execute method from running in this scenario?
Are there any specific service or threading considerations in Delphi XE 10 that I might be overlooking?
How can I better debug this issue to determine why the thread’s Execute method isn’t being called?
When I use TService.LogMessage(), it runs
enter image description here

The full code has been uploaded to github：https://github.com/ywlfff/WindowsServiceDemo

Is CnDebugger.LogMsg thread safe? Maybe the thread is executing but the log fails. What if you put a Beep() in there?

There is no version of Delphi named XE 10. Are you using Delphi XE or Delphi 10? They are completely different versions. In any case, the code looks fine, did you debug the service at runtime to make sure the OnStart event is firing and the thread is running? Where does CnDebugger.LogMsg()  save its log messages to, and are you sure that is working correctly? Do you have the same problem if you use TService.LogMessage() instead?

@JanDoggen Yes, beep() is not available in Windows Service applications. But I'm using the windows vcl desktop application, so I can use CnDebugger.LogMsg, and beep();

@雷米·勒博  I'm using the version I use: RAD Studio 10.4 Sydney。 CnDebugger.LogMsg will output the logs to an application called:CnDebugViewer.CnDebugger Just for debugging purposes, you can use any logging method instead

@RemyLebeau When I use TService.LogMessage(),windows logs in the Event viewer, it runs.thanks.

@user24964335 I am not familiar with CnDebugger/CnDebugViewer, is it possible that its log messages simply can't cross session boundaries? Remember that services and user apps run in separate sessions.

My assumption is that CnDebugger is a a global variable that hasn't been initialized by the time this thread kicks off and the Execute method is called, but you are running into an Access Violation referencing CnDebugger, but it's hard to tell with this limited view of code.
